# VS2012 Edit & Continue?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

My VS is acting strange. I'm trying to debug a web-app and doing some UI polishing, so normally I will make changes to a .aspx while the application is running and just reload the page. However anytime i make any change, even to an HTML element, VS is killing my session forcing me to re-login to the application.

I cant seem to ever get edit-and-continue to work when i want to modify a codebehind on the fly during debug.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen this behaviour with aspx files. However, for enabling Edit and Continue on code behind, go to project properties -> Web and check "Enable Edit and Continue".

Comment: Yea its strange, VS just decided to start doing it today, no changes to my environment, tried rebooting, still no luck!